# Is Spring Roo no longer supported?

Tags: spring, spring-roo

I used to use Roo for starting new projects and want to advocate for in our company, however I've stumbled upon the fact that it does not support Java 8 and there is a ticket for it: https://jira.spring.io/browse/ROO-3505
I found it some time ago and recently I went to check if it was updated and was surprised that it is still there. I paid attention though that the latest version of Spring Roo was released in January 2014 (1.2.5) and there were no more bug fixes or feature releases since.
It is especially strange in the light of the fact that recent Spring Core was significantly updated to support Java 8 last year (version 4.0.0 was released in December 2013)

Does it mean that Spring Roo project is dead and Spring Source has no plans to support it?

Comment: I'm asking this question here because SpringSource closed it's forum and migrated to StackOverflow instead. So this question is for SpringSource developers.

Comment: Roo development basically went off a cliff about two years ago, and it has land mines all over the place. I've switched to Groovy with liberal use of `@CompileStatic` instead.

Comment: And to the close voter: This question is absolutely not asking for tool recommendations, it's asking about the development state of a specific tool.

Comment: Thank you @chrylis I will check out Groovy. Good point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some months ago DISID and Pivotal reached an agreement on Roo project. Take a look at http://blog.gopivotal.com/pivotal/news-2/disid-to-lead-spring-roo-project

*Posted on April 24, 2014*

> We are happy to announce that Pivotal and DISID will collaborate on further development of the Spring Roo project. Roo will continue in its goal of providing a code-generation style of RAD framework, focused on helping developers get Java projects done on time. Pivotal and DISID have been collaborating around Roo for some time, so we’re excited to be formalizing what originally was an informal, developer led partnership, a partnership that DISID is committed to.

Comment: Hard to say if this is good news? Why isn't Spring/Pivotal taking the lead on this project? I know groovy/grails gets more attention in this arena, but I think there's a lot of good in Roo, especially in shops where Java is still king, and other languages aren't going to be supported-

Comment: I think that based on the current pulse the roo is dead.

Answer (score 6):

Spring Roo is back, they [released Version 1.3.0](https://spring.io/blog/2014/11/21/spring-roo-1-3-0-introduces-jdk-8-support) on 2014-11-21, it contains Java 8 support.

Answer (score 6):

According to [Spring Roo github page](https://github.com/spring-attic/spring-roo)... it is **DEPRECATED**.

> VMware has ended active development of this project, this repository
> will no longer be updated.

Answer (score 3):

I just submitted my second Roo bug fix (3rd actual pull request) the other day and plan to submit more over time, so I can say that Roo is no more dead than any other open source Java based tool with active contributors. I am also an active user of Roo, so I tend to fix bugs as I encounter them in my own projects.  So, despite its list of open issues and apparent lack of popularity at the current point, I still find it to be as useful if not moreso than most of the other Java tools out there.  If you want to help it along, why not convert some of the energy harping on the tool and come help make it better?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Perhaps if I spent more time commenting on posts here I might have a higher reputation score, but instead I am busy fixing Roo bugs.

Comment: Today Roo 1.3.0 has been released http://projects.spring.io/spring-roo/ ... so I think it isn't a dead project

Answer (score 1):

Spring Roo 2.0.0 has been released. Please download it at: https://projects.spring.io/spring-roo/#download-widget

See what’s new in Spring Roo 2.0: https://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/#getting-started-whatsNew

Answer (score 1):

Roo 2.0 is still on Java 1.8, which on Oracle's side is EOL. It is also not part or even installable in the latest STS 4.